Can't Save Message with Emoji on Go-Micro
So, I'm using Go-Micro for my API app, and this function is to store a message of a user sending a voucher to other user. I receive a problem where there are an error when user use emoji on the message. The error I get is like this:
{
    "id": "InternalServerError",
    "detail": "Terjadi kesalahan, cobalah beberapa saat lagi",
    "errorCode": 500,
    "devMessage": "Failed to receive response from server | {\"id\":\"go.micro.client\",\"code\":500,\"detail\":\"header key \\\"request\\\" contains value with non-printable ASCII characters\",\"status\":\"Internal Server Error\"}"
}

Then I try to debug my code, and I think I have a problem where my API-Gateway can't send a message with an emoji to my Service App. Here are the line of my code:
func (c *PromosHandler) PromosValidateUserRecipient(e echo.Context) error {
    // other code
    rsp, err := c.App.Promo.PromosValidateUserRecipient(ctx, req)

The request struct is like this:
type PromosValidateUserRecipientRequest struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    UserRecipient string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=userRecipient,proto3" json:"userRecipient,omitempty"`
    Message       string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=message,proto3" json:"message,omitempty"`
    ValueId       string `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=valueId,proto3" json:"valueId,omitempty"`
}

I wonder if there is any way to make my app can receive message using emoji.
I'm expecting that my doesn't crash or fail when a user send a message that contain emoji.
I don't want to make any change from the request because I want to handle it on the server-side.

This question is similar to: send emoji in http header ionic2. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The differences is that in this case I already put the emoji on the request body. But I still receive an error.

You can only use ASCII in the header. That is exactly what the error is telling you. "header key \"request\" contains value with non-printable ASCII character". It needs to be encoded.

so does this mean I need to encode the message from the front-end?
